# Deadlock issue with postgres and sqlalchemy: psycopg2.errors.DeadlockDetected: deadlock detected

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have Python FastAPI that is using sqlalchemy as ORM.
In production, I'm running 9 instances of uvicorn to run my API and it is managed by gunicorn. This is the command I'm running:

```
python -m gunicorn -b localhost:8080 -w 9 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker server.main:app
```

The problem I'm facing is a deadlock issue that appear from time to time. Here is the log of the issue:

```
 sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.errors.DeadlockDetected) deadlock detected
 DETAIL:  Process 1007755 waits for AccessExclusiveLock on relation 1232042 of database 16433; blocked by process 1007749.
 Process 1007749 waits for AccessExclusiveLock on object 3007868 of class 2620 of database 16433; blocked by process 1007755.
 HINT:  See server log for query details.
 [SQL:
 begin;
 drop trigger if exists notify_streams on frame;
 create trigger notify_streams
 after insert on frame
 for each row
execute procedure notify_channel_fn();
end;
 ]
```

Note: relation `1232042` is my `Frame` table and class `2620` is a `pg_trigger` instance.

Here is my `models.py` code file that is creating the procedure and the trigger:

```py
event.listen(
    Base.metadata,
    "after_create",
    DDL(
        """
            begin;

            SELECT pg_advisory_xact_lock(2142616474639426746); -- random 64-bit signed ('bigint') lock number

            create or replace function notify_channel_fn()
                returns trigger
                language plpgsql
            as $$
            declare
                begin
                    perform pg_notify(
                        new.stream_id::text,
                        new.frame_id::text
                    );
                    return null;
                end;
            $$;

            end;
        """
    ),
)

NOTIFY_STREAMS_TRIGGER_NAME = "notify_streams"

event.listen(
    Base.metadata,
    "after_create",
    DDL(
        f"""
            begin;

            drop trigger if exists {NOTIFY_STREAMS_TRIGGER_NAME} on frame;

            create trigger {NOTIFY_STREAMS_TRIGGER_NAME}
            after insert on frame
            for each row
            execute procedure notify_channel_fn();

            end;
        """
    )
)
```

Here is my table Frame:

```py
class Frame(Base):
    __tablename__ = "frame"

    stream_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("log.log_id"))
    frame_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    local_id = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    time_start = Column(DateTime(timezone=True), nullable=False)
    time_end = Column(DateTime(timezone=True), nullable=False)
    data = Column(JSON, nullable=False)

    log = relationship("Log", back_populates="frames")

    __table_args__ = (
        Index("frame_time_idx", stream_id.desc(), time_start.desc(), time_end.desc()),
        Index("frame_stream_idx", stream_id.desc(), local_id.desc()),
    )

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<Frame(stream_id={self.stream_id}, frame_id={self.frame_id})>"
```

Does anyone know why there is a deadlock here ?

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: What is the other process doing (you should be able to find it in `pg_stat_activity`)?